# Filtering the transitive group memberships of a user using Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to use the MS Graph SDK (beta) for C# to get all the groups a user belongs to transitively with a filter to only get "security groups".

My code looks like this:

```
var upn = "some.body@org.com";
 
var request = await _graphClient.Users[upn].TransitiveMemberOf
    .Request()
    .Filter("securityEnabled eq true")
    .GetAsync();
```

When I run this code, I get an error that `The specified filter to the reference property query is currently not supported`. I know that the same API endpoint *can* be called successfully using Postman with the same filter so I assume I'm missing something in my C# code?

Comment: Please provide a correlation id and time stamp and please share the Github sample  that your refering

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity No correlation ID is present in the error. `date: 2020-10-06T20:08:01` & `request-id: dad60f36-a67e-4e0d-ba7c-5d65161c73bf` & `client-request-id: dad60f36-a67e-4e0d-ba7c-5d65161c73bf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the below code for filtering the securityEnabled in c# using graph sdk

```
try
        {
            

            List<Option> requestOptions = new List<Option>();

            requestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));

        

            var request = await graphClient.Users["sruthi@xx.live"].TransitiveMemberOf
                .Request(requestOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .Filter("securityEnabled eq true")
                .GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sruthi's answer, I was able to get user transitive memberships. Obviously, this can often result in a huge list and the Graph API will only provide you a paginated response so you have to cycle through every page to get everything.

This is what the code looks like now:

```
public async Task<List<Group>> ListTransitiveGroupMembershipsOfUserAsync(string upn)
        {
            var requestOptions = new List<Option>
            {
                new QueryOption("$count", "true")
            };

            var directoryObjects = new List<DirectoryObject>();

            var request = await _graphClient.Users[upn].TransitiveMemberOf
                .Request(requestOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .Filter("securityEnabled eq true")
                .GetAsync();

            directoryObjects.AddRange(request.CurrentPage);

            while (request.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                var currentHeaders = request.NextPageRequest.Headers;
                IUserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage newPage;

                if (!currentHeaders.Any())
                    request = await request.NextPageRequest.Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual").GetAsync();
                else
                    request = await request.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();

                directoryObjects.AddRange(request.CurrentPage);
            }

            return directoryObjects.Cast<Group>().ToList();
        }
```

Initially, my code failed when it tried to get the results for page 2 onwards because it kept appending `eventual` to the `ConsistencyLevel` header. So when sending the HTTP request for page 2, the header was like: `ConsistencyLevel: eventual, eventual` or `ConsistencyLevel: eventual, eventual, eventual` for page 3 and so on so forth.

To get around this, I added the little `if (!currentHeaders.Any())` block to only add the `ConsistencyLevel` header if it doesn't already exist.

Hopefully that'll help anyone else who gets caught out by cycling through paginated responses!.

Comment: For future visitors here, you can use PageIterator to manage this paging process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp