# How to filter result to get groups based on users from AZure AD using Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting  groups from AZ AD based on users.  In one scnaior I need to get all but in other scenario I want to filter and only get groups based on the filter.  I used the below code but I am not getting data.

The groups that I need.  Technician, Research, ADMIN.  I want to just get these groups based on the useridenfiticaiton /email.

Below is the code:

GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphicClient(accessToken);

```
        List<Option> options = new List<Option>();
        options.Add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
        options.Add(new QueryOption("$filter", $"DisplayName eq 'Technician'"));
       // options.Add(new QueryOption("$filter", $"DisplayName eq 'Research'"));
        options.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));


        var groups = graphClient.Users[uniqueIdentification]
          .MemberOf
          .Request(options)
          .GetAsync().Result;
```

Note that I need to filter based on all 3 criteria. And be able to store the Group in a List object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if below is the cause as it may be possible.

Try by avoiding `result` in `.GetAsync().Result;` which may lead to `deadlock` condition which may probably lead to no result which looks like your case.

For example: *filtered for jobTitle* in query options:

```
    List<Option> requestOptions = new List<Option>();
          //var  requestOptions= new List<Option>(); 

    requestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", " jobTitle eq 'Retail Manager’ "));       
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", " jobTitle eq 'Marketing Assistant'"));       
   

     var request = await graphClient.Users["UPN"].MemberOf
                .Request(requestOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                 // .Filter("(jobTitle eq 'Retail Manager' ) or (jobTitle eq 'Marketing Assistant')")   // try this if query options doesn't work
                .GetAsync();
```

In graph explorer tried this :

[image]

But not sure later again it gives error as group doesn't have jobTitle as property.

Please check below **References:**

1. [Graph API .net SDK - Filter Me.MemberOf based on displayName of groups - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70337049/graph-api-net-sdk-filter-me-memberof-based-on-displayname-of-groups)
2. [c# - Filtering the transitive group memberships of a user using
   Graph SDK - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189818/filtering-the-transitive-group-memberships-of-a-user-using-graph-sdk)